# Does the Razz Berry actually make Pokemon easier to catch?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've just begun trying using Razz Berries for catching high leveled Pokemon, but it seems like instead of making it easier it get's harder to catch them. Whenever I use a Razz Berry my throws either fly to the right or to the left when I'm only throwing straight forward.

I find it harder when using Razz Berries because they use up so many of my Pokeballs, and when not using the berries it can take up to only 3-4 balls to capture a high leveled Pokemon with accurate throws. Is it supposed to turn my Pokeballs in a different direction when using Razz Berries? Is it part of the game in order to get more skilled throwing?

Answer (score 12):

No, the razz berries are not causing this. Razz berries do not affect your throw at all; they only make the Pokemon more likely to stay in the ball once you get them in there. Although it says it affects your next throw, you can tell it actually means your next "catch" because you cannot use another razz berry until you get the Pokemon into the ball.

It sounds like you may be having the same problem as described in the question [Ball curves on straight throw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274370/ball-curves-on-straight-throw), or perhaps you are throwing curve balls on accident, or you are just not throwing it as straight as you think you are.

There *are* a number of people that insist using a razz berry does curve the ball. I personally believe that this is a combination of coincidence and [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). People use razz berries on harder Pokemon, which tend to be farther away, which makes it more noticeable when a ball doesn't go where you expect it to. Once you start to believe that, you also tend to notice when the ball curves when using a razz berry and dismiss it when it curves without a razz berry.

I initially had this same thought when I first got access to razz berries, but some informal testing convinced me that it's not true. My personal experience has been that the ball is equally likely to curve on a far Pokemon whether I use a razz berry or not, and being more careful with my throws vastly increases the chance that the ball will go where I want it to.

Comment: I'm just trying to get answers, thanks for the link though it's appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate you wanting to clean up the site, but only questions can be flagged as a duplicate, not answers. This is because it's possible for two different questions to have the same answer. See for instance [this meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/951/47878).

Comment: Kat, fwiw, you can flag as duplicate using the 'flag' link below the question. I'm pretty sure that should be available to anyone no matter the rep.

Comment: I looked into it and you need 50 rep to flag as duplicate. I agree that this isn't a duplicate after all though, just possibly related.

Comment: Everyone is saying razz berries most definitely affect how easily it curves (especially unintentionally). This answer is blatantly wrong and ignores what people are experiencing. Sounds like you haven't played the game and just read the FAQ or something, tbh.

Comment: I'm not convinced. I think people use razz berries on harder Pokemon and an accidental curve ball is more noticeable. I get curve ball bonuses on easy Pokemon a LOT even though I wasn't trying to do one and the ball didn't curve noticeably because it didn't travel very far. I've personally had the ball go crazy on far Pokemon without using a razz berry as often as with using one.

Comment: @Matthew I edited in a couple more paragraphs to address this. I assure you that I do regularly play this game, and it is certainly not "everyone" that believes this. I even asked some of my friends if razz berries had caused their balls to curve and one looked at me like I was bonkers.  If you really believe otherwise then I encourage you to do some testing of your own (do something like play for an hour with no razz berries, count how many times it curves, then do it again with razz berries) and post your own answer.

Comment: @Kat I think that another possible cause is that people use their thumbs to swipe when throwing the Pokeball. Because of the way human hands are shaped, you're more likely to swipe off to one side if you do it this way. That's why I think using your index finger to swipe is more accurate. I've never noticed any curving at all with this method, regardless of whether I use a Razz berry or not.

Comment: @MageXy One of my friends that I polled said the same thing, and I have to agree. Using my index finger along with not trying to catch while walking or in direct sunlight has gotten rid of this problem for me. I might edit again when I get home from work. That would be a good answer for the question I linked, too!

Comment: @Kat I think the issue is that harder pokemon are farther away and people curve it because they're trying to swipe higher on the screen, and with thumbs it curves easier because of the natural direction of your thumb. Sorry for antagonizing you earlier! I was frustrated with the game, haha. I tested it again and it doesn't curve as much withmy index finger.

Comment: @Matthew no worries. I got a couple down votes, so it was nice to know why. I totally understand your frustration with this game!

Comment: @Kat apparently there was a bug and they fixed it. I can't find the source right now but there seemed to be a point in time where it *was* an issue. I'm not sure what's true to be totally honest, haha.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that what is happening is that the Pokemon that you are using razz berries on are the higher ones which means that they are further back and so you will be attempting to throw it further which leads to a longer swipe.

The problem is that you are swiping too far and for some reason if you swipe past the end of the screen the ball will become a curve ball and curve to the side.

I noticed this as it happened to me a lot of times when I was trying to catch a really high CP pokemon that was very far away.

I think that if you use AR mode you can aim the camera higher in order to not need to swipe as much to get the same distance. Other than that just try swiping shorter but faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try swipe lower next time I try.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me and a few of my friends too after using Razz berry. It is a glitch apparently. The ball curls away after I use a Razz berry making it impossible to catch a pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Razz berries mess up your throw on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that when this happens, turning on AR solves the problem, because I can angle my phone so that the pokemon is in the corner where the ball keeps going.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than a full fledged answer. Do you think you could maybe elaborate on your findings or experiences?